# Test seems to indicate routing error but works on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

The code below seems to run fine but the very basic test I implement seems to fail. As a test I have:

```
  test "should get contact" do
    get :contact
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Contact | #{@base_title}"
  end
```

This generates the error: `test_should_get_contact#MessagesControllerTest (2.11s) ActionController::UrlGenerationError: ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"contact", :controller=>"messages"}`

If I visit /contact on the server the page does show up, so it must be the test that is incorrect?

In routes.rb I have:

```
  get 'contact'           =>  'messages#new', as: 'contact'   # Not sure what "as: 'contact'" does but this in included in the tutorial I'm following.
  post 'contact'          =>  'messages#create'
```

In the messages controller:

```
  before_action :valid_email?, only: [:create]

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.valid?
      MessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to contact_path, notice: "Your messages has been sent."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "An error occurred while delivering this message."
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :content)
    end

    def valid_email?(email)
      email.present? && (email =~ VALID_EMAIL_REGEX)
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the action is `:new`, instead of `:contact`.
So, type this then it should be right :

```
get :new
```

The as: you defined in routes.rb

```
get 'contact'           =>  'messages#new', as: 'contact'
```

Allows you to get this path in your code like this :

```
contact_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
get :contact
```

Try:

```
get :new
```